# Chess engine Alpha Beta expected time to calculate depth 20

Tags: chess

I am working on a chess-like-game engine (its the same as chess except each player gets to make 2 moves), and would like to be able to calculate a search to around depth 8(which i guess translates to around depth 16 for regular chess or more since there is no pruning of  the 2-moves). I am running alphaBeta pruning.

Currently I seem to be able to get depth 6 (12+ for regular chess) within 20-30ish minutes. Relatively speaking how bad is this performance?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Each ply costs you a multiple of time equal to the number of moves being considered.

Answer (score 1):

If you need 20-30 mins to reach only depth 6, it'll take exponential more time to reach depth 8. So the answer is NO.

You should go back to your algorithm and check for any possible improvement. Null-move reduction, heavy pruning etc are required.